# findBy not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Why isn't this findBy method working?

```
def star(){
   print params.phone_number// print number 015658788 successfully

   def user = User.findByPhone_number(params.phone_number) //not working
   //def user = User.findByPhone_number("015658788") //working

   print user //print null

   if(user) {
      user.status=1
      println user.status
      user.save(flush:true)
   }
}
```

Comment: `User.findByPhone_number("015658788")` is working?

Comment: yes working @ codehx

Comment: I got the error that was white space problem  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def user = User.findByPhoneNumber(params.phone_number)
```

Comment: phone_number is column name so  PhoneNumber not work

Comment: where? on your domain object or on your db? If you are doing this on ur domain object that is bad idea, follow the grails way of variable naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

```
def user = User.findByPhoneNumber(Integer.parseInt(params.phone_number))
```

i suppose you are using Double

```
def user = User.findByPhoneNumber(Double.parseDouble(params.phone_number))
```